# ALSA + Qualcomm board

Tags: alsa, mplayer, mpd, qualcomm

I have a board that has a Qualcomm Snapdragon 210 (MSM8909). 
It's running a stock kernel (https://github.com/android-linux-stable/msm-3.18) with a Debian Stretch sysroot.
I got the sound working (by routing the DAI Frontends to the correct Backend) using the mixer_paths.xml file as an example, but I'm having some weird issues with Alsa and specific programs.

For instance, if I want to use the nrsc5 project (which uses libao for sound output), I got this error message and no sound at all:

`[ 6285.810132] msm_pcm_playback_copy: wait_event_timeout failed`

Same happens with `mpd` (using alsa with the default hw:0,0).

However, if I use `mplayer`, it works (I get some errors related to ctrl not found, but not big deal, I don't have a volume control in the end).
Same if I use aplay with wave files.

I tried to install `pulseaudio` and configure alsa as a default source, it "works", but it drops like crazy (and it doesn't use CPU at all). Mplayer says that 
`"Audio device got stuck!"`

The kernel that I'm using should have a patch that Qualcomm released about an error handling the timeouts (I checked this).

A quick note on the errors that I receive about the ctrl not found: Seems that the driver doesn't expose the "substream runtime"s, or something like that. However, I can modify the volume using some amixer commands (similar to the ones used in the DragonBoard410c, but tweaked accordingly to the mixer_paths.xml)

I don't know what else to do, because some apps that I would like to run, don't work properly, and they should.

Thanks!